# How to transfer my "hg log" from my old repository to new repository?

Tags: mercurial

For some reasons ,I messed up my old repository and I created a new repository. How to transfer my Mercurial log to the new repository(only the log not any other things).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot transfer just your "log", the log is the history of your repo, if the commits are not there, you won't get the corresponding log.

You need to clone or convert your repo to create a new one. If you "messed" it up, there could be a way to fix it, or at least just clone it up to a  certain revision where everything was still good. Once that is done, cherry-pick the missing revisions, if necessary.